# The function processes the sql request

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, flask, psycopg2

The function processes the sql request. It receives parameters and one of them can be either "null" or a value (uuid),
I need to add this value to where.
But there is a problem, because with null
"where param is null", but with the value "where param = value"

Example

```
sql = '''select name from table where param = %s '''
def run_sql(param=None):
    a = db_api(sql, param)
```

Comment: can't you use `if/else` ?

Comment: can you please show me on my example?

Comment: don't you know how to use `if/else` and run two different quersies for different data types ?

Comment: `if param == "null" : sql = '''select name from table where param is %s ''' else: sql = '''select name from table where param = %s '''`

Comment: I do not consider this approach, because the working sql query is much larger than in the example. I want to avoid duplication in code.

Comment: then use `if/else` with `sql = sql.replace('= %s', 'is %s')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
select name from table where param is not distinct from %s
```

In sql, `null = null` and `null <> null` always evaluate to `false` because null values are treated as unknown and can't be considered equal or unequal to each other.

But two `null` values are not distinct from each other, so `null is not distinct from null` evaluates to `true`.